# How to create custom formio check box component in angular

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, formio

i have one js file called as Checkbox.js,and i have app.component.ts file as follows...

AppComponent.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormioResources } from 'angular-formio/resource';
import { FormioAuthService } from 'angular-formio/auth';
import { AppConfig } from '../config';
import { FormioForm } from 'formiojs/full';
import from './Checkbox';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import BaseComponent from 'formiojs/components/base/Base';

import * as _ from "lodash";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  offlineCount = 0;
  offlineMode: any = null;
  offlineError = '';
  constructor(private auth: FormioAuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.auth.onLogin.subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });

    this.auth.onLogout.subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
    });

    this.auth.onRegister.subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });

    // Register our custom components.
    FormioForm.registerComponent('checkbox', Checkbox);
  }
}
```

Checkbox.js

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
/* import BaseComponent from '../base/Base'; */
import BaseComponent from 'formiojs/components/base/Base';

export default class CheckBoxComponent extends BaseComponent {
  static schema(...extend) {
    return BaseComponent.schema({
      type: 'checkbox',
      inputType: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Checkbox',
      key: 'checkbox',
      dataGridLabel: true,
      labelPosition: 'right',
      value: '',
      name: ''
    }, ...extend);
  }
 
  static get builderInfo() {
    return {
      title: 'Checkbox',
      group: 'basic',
      icon: 'fa fa-check-square',
      documentation: 'http://help.form.io/userguide/#checkbox',
      weight: 50,
      schema: CheckBoxComponent.schema()
    };
  }
 
  get defaultSchema() {
    return CheckBoxComponent.schema();
  }
 
  get defaultValue() {
    return this.component.name ? '' : (this.component.defaultValue || false).toString() === 'true';
  }
 
  get hasSetValue() {
    return this.hasValue();
  }
 
  elementInfo() {
    const info = super.elementInfo();
    info.type = 'input';
    info.changeEvent = 'click';
    info.attr.type = this.component.inputType || 'checkbox';
    info.attr.class = 'form-check-input';
    if (this.component.name) {
      info.attr.name = `data[${this.component.name}]`;
    }
    info.attr.value = this.component.value ? this.component.value : 0;
    return info;
  }
 
  build() {
    if (this.viewOnly) {
      return this.viewOnlyBuild();
    }
 
    if (!this.component.input) {
      return;
    }
    this.createElement();
    this.input = this.createInput(this.element);
    this.createLabel(this.element, this.input);
    if (!this.labelElement) {
      this.addInput(this.input, this.element);
    }
    this.createDescription(this.element);
    this.restoreValue();
    if (this.shouldDisable) {
      this.disabled = true;
    }
    this.autofocus();
    this.attachLogic();
  }
 
  get emptyValue() {
    return false;
  }
 
  isEmpty(value) {
    return super.isEmpty(value) || value === false;
  }
 
  createElement() {
    let className = `form-check ${this.className}`;
    if (!this.labelIsHidden()) {
      className += ` ${this.component.inputType || 'checkbox'}`;
    }
    this.element = this.ce('div', {
      id: this.id,
      class: className
    });
    this.element.component = this;
  }
 
  labelOnTheTopOrLeft() {
    return ['top', 'left'].includes(this.component.labelPosition);
  }
 
  labelOnTheTopOrBottom() {
    return ['top', 'bottom'].includes(this.component.labelPosition);
  }
 
  setInputLabelStyle(label) {
    if (this.component.labelPosition === 'left') {
      _.assign(label.style, {
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingLeft: 0,
      });
    }
 
    if (this.labelOnTheTopOrBottom()) {
      _.assign(label.style, {
        display: 'block',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingLeft: 0,
      });
    }
  }
 
  setInputStyle(input) {
    if (!input) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.component.labelPosition === 'left') {
      _.assign(input.style, {
        position: 'initial',
        marginLeft: '7px'
      });
    }
 
    if (this.labelOnTheTopOrBottom()) {
      _.assign(input.style, {
        width: '100%',
        position: 'initial',
        marginLeft: 0
      });
    }
  }
 
  createLabel(container, input) {
    const isLabelHidden = this.labelIsHidden();
    let className = 'control-label form-check-label';
    if (this.component.input
      && !this.options.inputsOnly
      && this.component.validate
      && this.component.validate.required) {
      className += ' field-required';
    }
 
    this.labelElement = this.ce('label', {
      class: className
    });
    this.addShortcut();
 
    const labelOnTheTopOrOnTheLeft = this.labelOnTheTopOrLeft();
    if (!isLabelHidden) {
      // Create the SPAN around the textNode for better style hooks
      this.labelSpan = this.ce('span');
 
      if (this.info.attr.id) {
        this.labelElement.setAttribute('for', this.info.attr.id);
      }
    }
    if (!isLabelHidden && labelOnTheTopOrOnTheLeft) {
      this.setInputLabelStyle(this.labelElement);
      this.setInputStyle(input);
      this.labelSpan.appendChild(this.text(this.component.label));
      this.labelElement.appendChild(this.labelSpan);
    }
    this.addInput(input, this.labelElement);
    if (!isLabelHidden && !labelOnTheTopOrOnTheLeft) {
      this.setInputLabelStyle(this.labelElement);
      this.setInputStyle(input);
      this.labelSpan.appendChild(this.text(this.addShortcutToLabel()));
      this.labelElement.appendChild(this.labelSpan);
    }
    this.createTooltip(this.labelElement);
    container.appendChild(this.labelElement);
  }
 
  createInput(container) {
    if (!this.component.input) {
      return;
    }
    const input = this.ce(this.info.type, this.info.attr);
    this.errorContainer = container;
    return input;
  }
 
  set dataValue(value) {
    const setValue = (super.dataValue = value);
    if (this.component.name) {
      _.set(this.data, this.component.key, setValue === this.component.value);
    }
    return setValue;
  }
 
  get dataValue() {
    const getValue = super.dataValue;
    if (this.component.name) {
      _.set(this.data, this.component.key, getValue === this.component.value);
    }
    return getValue;
  }
 
  get key() {
    return this.component.name ? this.component.name : super.key;
  }
 
  getValueAt(index) {
    if (this.component.name) {
      return this.inputs[index].checked ? this.component.value : '';
    }
    return !!this.inputs[index].checked;
  }
 
  getValue() {
    const value = super.getValue();
    if (this.component.name) {
      return value ? this.setCheckedState(value) : this.setCheckedState(this.dataValue);
    }
    else {
      return value;
    }
  }
 
  setCheckedState(value) {
    if (!this.input) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.component.name) {
      this.input.value = (value === this.component.value) ? this.component.value : 0;
      this.input.checked = (value === this.component.value) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else if (value === 'on') {
      this.input.value = 1;
      this.input.checked = 1;
    }
    else if (value === 'off') {
      this.input.value = 0;
      this.input.checked = 0;
    }
    else if (value) {
      this.input.value = 1;
      this.input.checked = 1;
    }
    else {
      this.input.value = 0;
      this.input.checked = 0;
    }
    if (this.input.checked) {
      this.input.setAttribute('checked', true);
    }
    else {
      this.input.removeAttribute('checked');
    }
    return value;
  }
 
  setValue(value, flags) {
    flags = this.getFlags.apply(this, arguments);
    if (this.setCheckedState(value) !== undefined) {
      return this.updateValue(flags);
    }
  }
 
  getView(value) {
    return value ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }
 
  destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    this.removeShortcut();
  }
}
```

when i am rendering check box component into my application,i am getting some errors like '=' required at import from './Checkbox' and can not find name Checkbox in appcomponent.ts file.

I want to create one component which are in Basic Components of formio like check box component,i want render that component into my application which should look like as shown below,on that instead of showing check matrix component i have to show check box component....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Aag.png)